# Tried all possible ways to turn php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off during Kayako 4 setup

Tags: .htaccess, magic-quotes-gpc

Tried all possible ways..
Right from the `php.ini` to `.htaccess` to turn `php_flag` `magic_quotes_gpc` off during `Kayako` 4 setup but all resulted in failure.

I have tried placing "`php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off`" in `.htaccess` file. and I placed a `php.ini` file in the root containing the code below:

```
[PHP]
magic_quotes_gpc
Default Value: Off
Development Value: Off
Production Value: Off
```

Still the setup shows that "Checking if magic quotes `GPC is disabled   FAILED`"

Please help me out.

I use Windows hosting based on Parallels Plesk Panel...

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign value to PHP parameter as well in the php.ini

[PHP]
magic_quotes_gpc = Off

Restart web service so that changes can be reflected!